# RecyclerView can't retrieving Json Object

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to display objects: 2nd and 3rd of the first array of the following json responses. But the RecyclerView.adapter doesn't showing anything

```
[
 [
   449613483,
   "-6.103334",
   "106.987316",
   "2019-05-16T00:00:09.000+07:00",
   0
 ],
 [
   449614907,
   "-6.103334",
   "106.987316",
   "2019-05-16T00:03:08.000+07:00",
   0
 ],
  ....
]
```

PlaybackFragment

```
mApiService.getHistory(token,units,startDate,endDate)
            .enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<Object>> call, @NonNull Response<ArrayList<Object>> response) {

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        assert response.body() != null;
                        playbackList=response.body();
                        for (int i=0; i<playbackList.size(); i++) {

                            first = playbackList.get(0);
                            firstList.add(first);
                        }

                        Log.d(TAG,"Response : "+playbackList);
                        Log.d(TAG,"First : "+first);

                        customAdapter= new CustomAdapter(playbackList, getContext());
                        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<Object>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

And this is my CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Object> playbackList;
private ArrayList<Object> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
private Object first, last;
private Context context;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView lat, lng, address;
    CardView cv_list_journey;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        lat = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);
        lng = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);
        address = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    }
}

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Object> playbackList, Context context){
    this.playbackList=playbackList;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  try {
        for (int i=0; i<playbackList.size(); i++) {
            first = playbackList.get(0);
            firstList.add(first);
            String lat1 = String.valueOf(firstList.get(1));
            String lng1 = String.valueOf(firstList.get(2));

            double startLatitude = Double.valueOf(lat1);
            double startLongitude = Double.valueOf(lng1);

            List<Address> addresses  = geocoder.getFromLocation(startLatitude,startLongitude, 1);
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

            holder.lat.setText(lat);
            holder.lng.setText(lng);
            holder.address.setText(address);
        }

        holder.cv_list_journey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error occured in: ", this.getClass().getName());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return first == null ? 0 : first.size(); }
}
```

I don't understand why the adapter can't get the Array.
The Error is RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: you are never using your `CustomAdapter`

Comment: sorry. I am using it of course

Comment: you didn't show how you use it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the adapter in main thread and update it in service callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getItemCount() { 
return playbackList == null ? 0 : playbackList.size();
}
```

here you are binding your array list with playbackList in constructor
 that why in getItemCount method playbackList.size is used  or

```
this.firstList = playbackList
```

add this in your constructor then use that and don't initialize firstList .

Comment: ya, list is showing now. but onBindViewHolder still not working properly

Comment: final  Object pojo = playbackList.get(position);   holder.address.setText(pojo.getAddressLine );  create the object of your model class then get the values like this it do not require the for loop it will automatically iterate every value of your array list

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
first == null ? 0 : first.size();
```

with

```
playbackList == null ? 0 : playbackList.size();
```

Modify this also

```
todayAdapter = new TodayAdapter(firstList, getContext());
```

And now remove try/catch and for loop from onBindViewHolder and add below code.

```
        String lat1 = String.valueOf(playbackList.get(1));
        String lng1 = String.valueOf(playbackList.get(2));

        double startLatitude = Double.valueOf(lat1);
        double startLongitude = Double.valueOf(lng1);

        List<Address> addresses  = geocoder.getFromLocation(startLatitude,startLongitude, 1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

        holder.lat.setText(lat);
        holder.lng.setText(lng);
        holder.address.setText(address);
```

Comment: the list is show but with many item. I just want to display 1 item which is the first array. however the onBindViewHolder still not working properly.

Comment: You are looping through playbackList but not using i. see this first = playbackList.get(0). May I know why.?

Comment: check my modified answer@bagusiluvaglobal